# How to define handler in a AWS lambda docker image

Tags: bash, docker, aws-lambda

I am deploying a Docker container on AWS Lambda with the below content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli:2.12.3

# hadolint ignore=DL3033
RUN yum update -y \
    && yum install -y bash curl git jq make tar unzip xmlstarlet zip \
    && yum clean all \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

WORKDIR /opt

ENTRYPOINT []

COPY ./test.sh ./

CMD ["sh", "./test.sh"]
```

and inside my test.sh I'm printing :
test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eo pipefail

echo "Inside Lambda"
```

Now, when I test this lambda I'm observing two weird things:

1. "Inside Lambda" is printed twice. Seems like I'm also running test.sh and lambda itself is also running test.sh
2. Final out of the lambda is error state: "Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason" : May be I need to pass a signal that script run successfully.

Please help me to solve these two issues. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using SAM, CDK or are you manually creating functions via the console?

Comment: Creating the function manually right now.

Comment: Could you share more details on what programming language are you going to run inside the Lambda? I could not see anything that Lambda could use to handle incoming requests on this function so I think that is the problem with your setup.

Comment: No programming language. I've selected "Container image" to deploy lambda function. I want to run a bash script(it will do some curl and download the logs and save those logs to s3) and printing hello inside that script right now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not a good use of the underlying technology.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a container-based Lambda off of a totally custom Docker image. It should use one of the base images and it has to use a Runtime Interface Client to be compatible with Lambda. There are a few RIEs already available: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

To just stick to bash + docker-based Lambda, you would have to write your custom RIE as there's no official one for bash. In the past I used Python-based images to invoke the bash scripts from Python - it worked quite nicely.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've resolved my error by using `amazon/aws-lambda-provided:al2` image.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my issue by using the following dockerfile to run a bash script:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-provided:al2


RUN yum update -y \
    && yum install -y bash curl jq make awscli \
    && yum clean all \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

WORKDIR /var/runtime/
COPY ./bootstrap ./bootstrap
RUN chmod 755 ./bootstrap

WORKDIR /var/task/
COPY ./download_logs.sh ./
RUN chmod 755 ./script.sh

CMD ["script.sh.handler"]
```

Comment: What is that ./bootstrap file?